# Tongue position issues in the American bunched r sound

Tags: phonetics

I'm training my american bunched  r sound and I'd really need someone to help me solve my linguistic issues.
1) should I feel every part of my tongue tight or just the back sides are enough?
2) If I have to feel my tongue tight everywhere should my tongue tip keep low or I can slightly raise it? It is pretty tough for me to keep my tongue tip tight without raising it.

Comment: I think this question would be more appropriate in "English Language & Usage". I would recommend that you record and listen to yourself speaking and then compare it with a native speaker.